# VBNET remove network drive: network connection does not exist / local device name is already in use

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck in a rather funky situation. Long story short I am trying to remove/disconnect a network drive using a VB.NET script, without success for now. We will call this drive V, and it used to be stored in a remote server -it does not exist anymore.

The target path of that network drive was removed and hence it is not possible to locate it, so we want to remove it from our workstations. As I said, V was stored in a remote server...yet somehow in 'My Computer' it is identified as a Hard Disk Drive (ie. local, like C:). Interacting with V, either by clicking or via a script, will produce the following error:

`the network connection does not exist`

To remove it, I created this simple script:

```
 driveLetter = "V:"
 path = "***"          'hidden for security purposes
 mapDrives(objNetwork, driveLetter, path)

'---

Sub mapDrives(ByVal objNetwork, ByVal driveLetter, ByVal path)
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting old " & driveLetter & " ...")
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive(driveLetter)
        Console.WriteLine(driveLetter & " disconnected.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Console.WriteLine(" Mapping new " & driveLetter & "...")
        objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive(driveLetter, path)
        Console.WriteLine(driveLetter & " mapped successfully.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Using powershell, I double check whether that drive is there or not. I type `gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'`, which returns a list of all the drives available, both local and remote. I get all the drives, both local and remote. V is not part of that list.

Next step I check int he registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2` to see if there is any garbage entry there that was not removed. All the entries there correspond with active network drives; V is not there.

Next I try just to remap V: to some other existing remote location. I get the following error:

```
The local device name is already in use
```

So basically everything tells me that V is not there and hence should be available, yet it still appears as a local disk and it is not possible to interact with it, nor map towards somewhere else. It will not show up either when trying to hide it via group policy.

FYI, our workstations run windows 7, and the script was done in VBNET. It used to be written in VBS, which we thought could be the problem and hence I migrated it to VBNET. The script will work well with any other drive.

Any suggestions? :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `NET USE v: "\\somepath\"` work at command prompt? If so you could perform that using the `diagnostics.process`

Comment: if i run that with somepath= path to an existing remote location, i get system error 67: network name cannot be found.

Comment: you don't need an = sign. Just type the path in "". Make sure you can browse to the path in case it isn't a valid share or you don't have permission

Comment: i think there is a misunderstanding here. I typed: 

net use v: "\\\*****\"   where *** is a valid remote location :)

Comment: if you just type the location at run, do you have access to it?

Comment: nope :/ there's a popup that says location is not available

Comment: If you only want to remove the mapping, `NET USE /Delete /Y` will work, if you need to replace the mapping, then the path needs to be available

Comment: @James: tried that already to no success :/  It returns "network connection could not be found"

Comment: The problem is with the machine or network. Its not a programming issue as it doesn't even work with windows commands. You should probably checkout http://superuser.com/